# Connect a Device to Thingsboard

Tags: thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

I want to connect a medical device to thingsboard. I have already connected the device to a router. The Device sends XML Data to the routers IP address in a specific port. I need to get this data in my thingsboard instance. I have a thingsboard community edition.

I need to know a step by step process on how do achieve this.

I have researched online and found a few ways, but couldn't grasp it. because I'm new to thingsboard.

I Need to know a simple process on how to do this.